# { [Error: socket hang up] code: 'ECONNRESET' }

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, google-api, request

So I'm using [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) inside [async.each](https://github.com/caolan/async) and after calling a few requests it gives me { [Error: socket hang up] code: 'ECONNRESET' }. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

```
async.eachSeries(videos, function (video, next) {
    if (initialVideosObj[video.id] == false) {
        var url = config.youtubeApiUrl + "videos?part=contentDetails,snippet,player&key=" + config.youtubeKey + "&regionCode=" + config.regionCode + "&id=" + video.id
        request(url, function (error, response, body) {
            if (error) {
                console.error("ERROR:", error, url);// afet a few requests it gives me { [Error: socket hang up] code: 'ECONNRESET' }, but the funny thing is that the logged url has no problem when I call it manually!
                next(error);
            } else if (response.statusCode == 200) {
                var parsedVideoData = JSON.parse(body);
                video["duration"] = convertDuration(parsedVideoData.items[0].contentDetails.duration);
                video["yt_subscribe_id"] = parsedVideoData.items[0].snippet.channelId;                                                        
                next();
            }
        });
    } else {
        setImmediate(next);//Since there is no async operation I use setImmediate!
    }
}, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err.stack, err);
    } else {                                                
        console.log("Done")
    }
});
```

**UPDATED:**

This is the error stack I got:

```
{ [Error: socket hang up] code: 'ECONNRESET' }
/myProj/node_modules/longjohn/dist/longjohn.js:185
        throw e;
              ^
/myProj/getVideo.js:207:71,done (/myProj/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:126:15),/myProj/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:32:16,/myProj/getVideo.js:141:45,Request._callback (/myProj/getVideo.js:399:13),self.callback (/myProj/node_modules/request/request.js:354:22),Request.emit (events.js:107:17),Request.onRequestError (/myProj/node_modules/request/request.js:1011:8)
```

Comment: Can you use https://github.com/mattinsler/longjohn to get long stack traces that will contain the async operations and show the stack trace please.

Comment: How does it work? should I just install and require it? thats all? documentation doesn't have any example!

Comment: Hey @KietThanhVo I added error stack now;

Answer (score 0):

How fast are these requests being sent? Maybe you're hitting their rate limits? See https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota for more details. This would explain why doing it manually never gives you the error.